# Installing GD in Docker

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I am a complete Docker novice but am having to maintain an existing system. The Dockerfile I am using is as below:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y sendmail

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

When I run 'docker build [sitename]' everything seems ok until I get the error:

```
configure: error: png.h not found.
The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install gd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You should add the `libpng-dev` package to your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y sendmail libpng-dev

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Then go to directory with `Dockerfile` and run:

`docker build -t sitename .`

It worked in my case:

```
Removing intermediate container f03522715567
Successfully built 9d69212196a2
```

Let me know if you get any errors.

**EDIT:**

You should see something like this:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sitename            latest              9d69212196a2        19 minutes ago      414 MB
<none>              <none>              b6c69576a359        25 minutes ago      412.3 MB
```

**EDIT2:**

Just to double check everything:

Please run the `docker build` command this way:

`docker build -t sitename:1.0 .`

(adding `:1.0` should not change anything, I added it just to have additional row in `docker images` output)

Then start the container:

`docker run --name sitename_test -p 80:80 sitename:1.0`

It should work just fine.

I assumed that apache is using standard port (80) - maybe you need to adjust that. If you have other services/containers listening on port 80 you can make your container listening on other port:

`docker run --name sitename_test -p 8080:80 sitename:1.0`

That will redirect the traffic from port 8080 to port 80 "inside" the container.

Normally you run container in the background. To do this add the `-d` option to the `docker run` command (but for testing purposes you can omit `-d` to see output in the console).

If you decide to run container in the background you can check logs using `docker logs sitename_test`. To follow the logs (and see updates in logs) use `-f` option:

`docker logs -f sitename_test`

Comment: That seemed to build but while doing so I got a few lines in red appear; are these fails?

Comment: Please paste those lines. I have done that build but did not get any warnings/errors.

Comment: Also when I check 'docker images' it says there was a build run at the time I ran it, but the Repository column has 'None' against it.

Comment: Please check the edited answer - formatting in comments does not work :/

Comment: I do get the list as you show it, but all the top lines are <none> <none>. When I go to the front end site the docker installation is linked to it says the modules are still missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124037/discussion-between-lmtx-and-evilscary).

Comment: Using this method  will install incomplete gd, Some functions don't work!

Comment: Why libpng-dev and not libpng? Isnt that not secure?

Comment: E: Package 'libpng-dev' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 33):

It is not the case of the OP, but I found that for those that are using `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` the syntax is a bit different

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

# ... Other instructions ...

# Setup GD extension
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      freetype \
      libjpeg-turbo \
      libpng \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
      --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
      # --with-png=/usr/include/ \ # No longer necessary as of 7.4; https://github.com/docker-library/php/pull/910#issuecomment-559383597
      --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && apk del --no-cache \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

# ... Other instructions ...
```

Comment: php:7.4 is the key

Comment: For me it seems removing `libpng-dev` makes `gd` unable to load

Answer (score 32):

This answer is too late, but it will help.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ && \
docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: Options for docker-php-ext-configure have changed. now it's docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg.  See https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/912

Comment: @BradyEmerson is right. You need to replace the options for `docker-php-ext-configure` as mentioned in the above comment and then works as expected.

Comment: Old
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd
--with-png-dir=/usr/include/
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/

New
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd
--with-png=/usr/include/
--with-jpeg=/usr/include/
--with-freetype=/usr/include

Source - https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/931#issuecomment-568658449

Comment: Just saved me from scraping the project :p
No answers found anywhere

Comment: @AransiolaOluwaseun I got unrecognized options for --with-png. Can you confirm?

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: This worked for me on my Macbook M1 Chip Docker containerr
using the php image arm64v8/php:7.4-fpm.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: From PHP 7.4.0+ the image option are rename without dir
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/image.installation.php

Answer (score 23):

This `Dockerfile` worked with Php7
https://hub.docker.com/r/giapnh/php7-gd

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libwebp-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev 

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring

RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you needed to change to make it work? Just dumping that code here does not help anybody to learn from your answer

Comment: Not dumping the code but the following fixed the error: function 'imagecreatefromjpeg' not found.
```RUN apt-get install -y libwebp-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd```

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, some php extensions have dependencies to other programs. There is a project called [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) that you can use to install PHP extensions. It will make sure that the required dependencies are present as well.

Since I need that external script in multiple containers, I've put it in [a shared script](https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/structuring-the-docker-setup-for-php-projects/#shared-folder) that I then include in the required Dockerfile.

**Script (at .shared/scripts/install_php_extensions.sh)**

```
#!/bin/sh

# add wget
apt-get update -yqq && apt-get -f install -yyq wget

# download helper script
wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions \
    || (echo "Failed while downloading php extension installer!"; exit 1)

# install all required extensions
chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && install-php-extensions \
    gd \
;
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# get the scripts from the build context and make sure they are executable
COPY .shared/scripts/ /tmp/scripts/
RUN chmod +x -R /tmp/scripts/

# install extensions
RUN /tmp/scripts/install_php_extensions.sh
```

Caution: Make sure to use the correct [build context](https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/structuring-the-docker-setup-for-php-projects/#understanding-build-context) in this case.

Comment: I wish I used the repo earlier. I had to search my browser history to upvote your answer. Thanks. And also, using this project keeps the image lighter as it removes the unnecessary dependencies after the installation is done.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 8.2:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-alpine
...
RUN apk add libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd ...
```

composer.json:

"require": {
"php": ">=8.2",
"ext-gd": "*",

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.4 and above

```
FROM wordpress:php7.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    zlib1g-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-webp --with-jpeg \
    --with-xpm --with-freetype && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the steps for those who are facing the issue while installing `BlueSpiceFoundation` extension in MediaWiki 1.38

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

This is how we have solved. BTW, the PHP version is `7.4.32`