# PHP intl extension in Docker container

Tags: php, docker, php-extension, intl

I'm trying to load the intl PHP extension in my Docker container, but it doesn't seem to work.

Have already tried this https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/57 but I still get the same error message:

```
configure: error: in `/usr/src/php/ext/intl':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

My Docker file looks like this:

```
RUN apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get install -y libicu-dev\
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl
```

and it's loading from php:fpm

Have anyone gone through this and got to solve the problem? It's getting me nuts.

Answer (score 85):

Your code worked perfectly for me once I added a space before the backslash terminating the second line of the run command:

```
RUN apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get install -y libicu-dev \ ### <-- Added space here
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Comment: This is the right answer. All commands also works fine for PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.3 on Docker. Just a reminder: IntlDateFormatter is a good substitute for strftime, which has been deprecated in PHP8.1.

Comment: This fixed the issue of "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "UConverter" not found..." with PHP 8.2

Answer (score 18):

It seems some requirements are missing. The snippet below worked for me:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=5.6
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-jessie

apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ \
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, some php extensions have dependencies to other programs. There is a project called [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) that you can use to install PHP extensions. It will make sure that the required dependencies are present as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224300/413531 for an example how I actually integrate it in a Dockerfile.

Comment: Best answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For older build scripts, this problem may be caused by icu-devtools recently dropping icu-config. On debian, it can be fixed by downgrading libicu-dev and icu-devtools:

```
apt-get install libicu-dev=57.1-6+deb9u4 icu-devtools=57.1-6+deb9u4
```

To determine the specific version that may work for you, just do:

```
apt-cache policy libicu-dev
```

And choose a version up to ~60. Same for icu-devtools.

I found this problem while trying to build a docker image for PHP 7.1. For more context, check [debian bug report 920900](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=920900).