# When executing this docker command why do I get php extension errors?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, silverstripe

I have a composer.json file that should install silverstripe and some other things:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "type": "silverstripe-recipe",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/onfire/Silverstripe-Recaptcha"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "silverstripe/recipe-plugin": "^1.2",
        "silverstripe/recipe-cms": "^4.4",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "~3.2.0",
        "symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions": "^3.2",
        "silverstripe/subsites": "^2",
        "silverstripe/restfulserver": "^2.1",
        "wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps": "^2.1",
        "undefinedoffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha": "^2.0",
        "i-lateral/silverstripe-googleshoppingfeed": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
    },
    "extra": {
        "project-files-installed": [
            "app/.htaccess",
            "app/_config.php",
            "app/_config/mysite.yml",
            "app/src/Page.php",
            "app/src/PageController.php"
        ],
        "public-files-installed": [
            ".htaccess",
            "index.php",
            "install-frameworkmissing.html",
            "install.php",
            "web.config"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I'm trying to install these using this command:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install
```

The command executes but outputs:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file Your requirements
>   could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for silverstripe/framework 4.5.0 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/framework[4.5.0].
>       - silverstripe/framework 4.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.   Problem 2
>       - silverstripe/framework 4.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps 2.1.5 requires silverstripe/framework ^4 -> satisfiable by
>   silverstripe/framework[4.5.0].
>       - Installation request for wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps[2.1.5].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /usr/local/etc/php/php-cli.ini
>       - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
>       - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in
>   CLI mode.

This works well for example with Laravels composer.json file, why does it not work with this one?

Also what exactly is happening here and how do I resolve the errors? Since the command I am using is creating a temporary container is this even possible using this method?

I do not want to install composer on my system so this method is a requirement.

Comment: The error output tells us the problem: "the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system". The intl extension needs to be installed / enabled on your system's php environment.

Comment: Presuming you are using the php container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674297/php-intl-extension-in-docker-container