# CodeIgniter 4 problem installing with manual

Tags: codeigniter-4

CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException
The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: {0}.
SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php at line 224

Answer (score 12):

I faced same issue and resolve by following below steps:

1. go to the app=> Config => Boot => production.php in your project
2. Change the ini_set('display_errors', '0') to ini_set('display_errors', '1')
   above will show you the error detail then do the following:
3. Open [xampp_folder_path]/php/php.ini to edit.
4. Search for ;extension=intl and remove the ;.
5. Save the php.ini file and restart Apache.

reference/thanks to:
[Chibueze Agwu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58409729/5035262) and [mail2bapi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250711/5035262)

Answer (score 1):

Look for the php.ini file(C:\xampp\php\php.ini:921)
and search for the

> extension=intl

line, and
uncomment. Then run the command `php spark serve`, in the terminal of your application path.

Answer (score 0):

## For linux user:

### the php used by the apache webserver

```
/etc/php/{version}/apache2/php.ini
```

### the php used by the terminal/command line

```
/etc/php/{version}/cli/php.ini
```

In both case (apache/cli), Search for ;extension=intl and remove the ;.

The next to do is to install the extension if not exist

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
```

Afterwards, restart your apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Voila, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Docker` and an `apache` image, you need to configure the `php intl` extension:

```
FROM php:7.4.27-apache-buster

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl;

...
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650040/3701102