# Docker Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, docker

I try to install GD, because I'm getting the error "Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()".

When building the image I'm getting the error

```
E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg62-turbo-dev
E: Unable to locate package libpng12-dev
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev && docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 --with-png-dir=/usr/include --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include && docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-fpm

# Install GD
RUN apt-get install -y \
libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libpng12-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 \
--with-png-dir=/usr/include \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd \
&& docker-php-ext-enable gd
```

What's the right way to install GD?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657058/installing-gd-in-docker Have a look there

Answer (score 0):

What about running `apt-get update` first to update local list of packages? It should always be run before installing:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes libfreetype6-dev ....
```

Comment: Ok, I've updated my Dockerfile. I'm a newbie to Docker, what to run now? I'm using a docker-compose.yml. docker-compose up -d seems not to update the image..

Comment: After updating `Dockerfile` you need to rebuild it. You can do it manually running `docker build -t my-image .` in the folder, containing `Dockerfile` and then refer it as `my-image`. Or you may configure `docker-compose` to do that.

Comment: Great, thanks! But when working in a dev team, what is the best approach? I can't ask everybody to run docker build. So updating docker-compose will be the best way? How does it look like?

Comment: Simple. Update you `docker-compose.yml` according to this doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build and launch  `docker-compose` with `--build` argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to offical image [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/php):

If you are having difficulty figuring out which Debian or Alpine packages need to be installed before docker-php-ext-install, then have a look at [the install-php-extensions](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) project. to install the GD extension you simply have to **add these to lines to Dockerfile** and get ride of everty things:

```
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions gd
```