# Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg()

Tags: php, laravel

[image]
Hi all,
The error is displayed when I post a pic.jpeg.

I tried to install php7.0-gd but it didn't install.

What should I need my dockerfile?

can you please look into and help.

```
root@2213ad6df220:/var/www/html/laravel-app# sudo apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.0-thrift' for regex 'php7.0'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-remctl' for regex 'php7.0'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-common' for regex 'php7.0'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-curl' for regex 'php7.0'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
root@2213ad6df220:/var/www/html/laravel-app# sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-gd'
```

```php
FROM php:7.2-fpm
# install composer
RUN cd /usr/bin && curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php && ln -s /usr/bin/composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
git \
zip \
unzip \
vim
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
   && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install libzip-dev libicu-dev libonig-dev \
  zlib1g-dev \ 
  libjpeg-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath gd 
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Comment: Intervention Image requires one of the following image libraries. GD Library (>=2.0) … or 
Imagick PHP extension (>=6.5.7)

Comment: Check if this solves your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657058/installing-gd-in-docker#:~:text=%23%20Setup%20GD%20extension%20RUN%20apk,%2Fpull%2F910%23issuecomment%2D

Comment: i think it's just php-gd not php7.0-gd.

Comment: also php-gd was error.